# ggplot grouped plot scale colour gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying (and failing) to use a scale_fill_gradient() in a group `ggplot` figure. I am using the following data and `ggplot` code.

I am trying to get something similar to the following but for each group (colours do not have to be the same just trying to scale the gradient of the colour)

[image]

```
ggplot(xy, aes(x=Year, y=Gain, group=Gain, label=Variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", fill="#9C27B0", position="dodge") +
  geom_text(position=position_dodge(width=0.9), hjust=-0.05) +
  ggtitle("Feature Importance (All years)") +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=unique(xy$Year)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw(base_size = 11, base_family = "") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="red", mid="yellow", high="green")
```

Data:

```
xy <- structure(list(Variable = c("CF.NCL", "DailySALES.EBIT", "EBIT.FinExp", 
"EQ.Turnover", "SALES.WC", "CA.CL", "CA.TA", "TL.EQ", "CL.FinExp", 
"TL.TA", "logTA", "TL.EQ", "DailySALES.EBIT", "CF.NCL", "CA.CL", 
"SALES.WC", "EQ.Turnover", "CL.FinExp", "CA.TA", "EBIT.FinExp", 
"TL.TA", "logTA", "SALES.WC", "DailySALES.EBIT", "TL.EQ", "CA.CL", 
"CF.NCL", "CA.TA", "CL.FinExp", "EQ.Turnover", "EBIT.FinExp", 
"TL.TA", "logTA", "SALES.WC", "TL.EQ", "EQ.Turnover", "CA.TA", 
"CA.CL", "CL.FinExp", "CF.NCL", "DailySALES.EBIT", "logTA", "TL.TA", 
"EBIT.FinExp"), Gain = c(0.0249669149256489, 0.0284788358072123, 
0.0416885482543631, 0.0481161711992678, 0.0484199735868597, 0.0494398516158408, 
0.0771009818151621, 0.0835709725586987, 0.0922406378720892, 0.120398717131196, 
0.385578395233662, 0.0188783661019333, 0.0197853002129162, 0.0272749207536935, 
0.0347284667673124, 0.0430992866122089, 0.0435834750808189, 0.0631609275004249, 
0.0641364686807323, 0.0787809479913172, 0.212397184938682, 0.39417465535996, 
0.0210381458789509, 0.0279003966700287, 0.0321333141168294, 0.0337989653595418, 
0.0450490096266459, 0.0491798397528832, 0.0661536580122029, 0.0734706661210229, 
0.135767436486281, 0.167947601913985, 0.347560966061628, 0.0139475947749436, 
0.0186058318290004, 0.0223217808071512, 0.0244533394205631, 0.0257086851408409, 
0.0410344050892873, 0.0530577543373713, 0.119669956742959, 0.153321518346671, 
0.169880049476648, 0.357999084034564), Year = c("FourthYear", 
"FourthYear", "FourthYear", "FourthYear", "FourthYear", "FourthYear", 
"FourthYear", "FourthYear", "FourthYear", "FourthYear", "FourthYear", 
"ThirdYear", "ThirdYear", "ThirdYear", "ThirdYear", "ThirdYear", 
"ThirdYear", "ThirdYear", "ThirdYear", "ThirdYear", "ThirdYear", 
"ThirdYear", "SecondYear", "SecondYear", "SecondYear", "SecondYear", 
"SecondYear", "SecondYear", "SecondYear", "SecondYear", "SecondYear", 
"SecondYear", "SecondYear", "FirstYear", "FirstYear", "FirstYear", 
"FirstYear", "FirstYear", "FirstYear", "FirstYear", "FirstYear", 
"FirstYear", "FirstYear", "FirstYear")), row.names = c(NA, -44L
), vars = "Year", drop = TRUE, indices = list(33:43, 0:10, 22:32, 
    11:21), group_sizes = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), biggest_group_size = 11L, .Names = c("Variable", 
"Gain", "Year"), labels = structure(list(Year = c("FirstYear", 
"FourthYear", "SecondYear", "ThirdYear")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), vars = "Year", drop = TRUE, indices = list(c(0L, 1L, 5L, 
6L, 8L, 15L, 24L, 33L, 36L, 38L, 41L), c(7L, 11L, 16L, 20L, 21L, 
23L, 29L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 42L), c(4L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 19L, 22L, 
27L, 28L, 35L, 37L, 40L), c(2L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 17L, 18L, 25L, 26L, 
30L, 39L, 43L)), group_sizes = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), biggest_group_size = 11L, .Names = "Year"), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Current plot:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is something similar to; (but I have different data)

[image]

Comment: What variable do you want to determine the fill of the bar? In your code, you hardcoded a color for fill: `fill="#9C27B0"`, so obviously it won't change. Have you tried adding a `fill=` argument to your `aes` function?

Comment: I have tried many different combinations without success. The `ggplot` code I sent was the last version I tried. What I am trying to get is to start from the "darkest" colour at the highest bar chart which in most cases is `logTA` and the "lightest" colour with the worst performing bar chart in each plot.

Comment: What exactly do you want this to look like? The example has one observation per x-value, so they don't need to worry about stacking bars, whereas yours has multiple observations at each x-value (`Year`). Is year really what you want on the x-axis? Or maybe an interaction between `Year` & `Variable`, or counts for each year? Consider also the fact that all the `Gain` values add up to 1 for each year

Comment: `scale_fill_*` doesn't do anything unless there is a defined `fill` aesthetic for it to scale. Add a `fill` aesthetic to `aes` and show us that code and the plot that gives. It's hard to think about what's causing your real problem when we don't know what you're trying to get.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to make 4 separate `scale_fill_gradient` colours, indicating the "best" bar chart with the highest "fill" and the weakest bar chart with the lowest colour "fill" - in terms of aesthetics I am hoping it to look like the image in the original post but produced for 4 different plots.

Comment: I am trying to get the same results as I have at the moment but the gradient look "similar" to the figure posted in the original post (colours are not important) just trying to get the gradient colour scheme working (which I am unable to do)

Comment: You'll need a variable in your dataset to determine what color each bar should be. Then, if you add `fill = group` to your `aes`, the bars will be colored by group. You can then add a `scale_fill_*` function to set those colors.

Comment: Is it not more simple than that? can I not apply the same ´scale_fill_*` to all four bar plots?

Comment: Are you making a plot with 4 bars, or 4 separate bar plots? Either way, if you want to scale the `fill`, you need a `fill` aesthetic to be defined in `aes`

Comment: I have edited the original comment to show the plot: I am aiming at, different gradient colours for each bar, within each plot.  So for plot "first year" I hope to have a gradient, and again the same gradient for "second year", "third year" etc. Instead of a simple fixed fill.

Comment: The four different grouped plots are independent, I am trying to get the same colour gradient for each plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps you:

```
colrs=c()
for (i in unique(xy$Year)){
  gainx=xy$Gain[xy$Year==i]
colrs=c(colrs,colorRampPalette(c("darkblue", "lightblue" ))(length(gainx))[rank(gainx)])
}


ggplot(xy, aes(x=Year, y=Gain, group=Gain, label=Variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", fill=colrs, position="dodge") +
  geom_text(position=position_dodge(width=0.9), hjust=-0.05) +
  ggtitle("Feature Importance (All years)") +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=unique(xy$Year)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw(base_size = 11, base_family = "") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="red", mid="yellow", high="green")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes thank you so much, such a headache for me trying to solve this one!